# Clean minibuffer during file find in ido mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `C-a,C-k` to clean minibuffer when searching for a file in normal emacs. In ido mode, this key is bound to deleting a file.

So, in ido mode, after going deep down the folder hierarchy, how to clean minibuffer and restart my file selection from root folder.

Yes, i can use backspace to go up one step at a time, but that is tedious....

Comment: Just type `//` and you're at root. No need to complicate things.

Comment: yes abo-abo, rite... but '~' symbol after // doesn't work..  it says, /~[No match]. doesn't ~ symbol take you to home directory?

Comment: See http://oremacs.com/2015/01/09/ido-find-file-tilde/

Comment: @MadhavanKumar, follow the `~` with `/` and you should get to your home directory.